# Android app optimization regarding images

Tags: android, image, optimization

The application I am working on will have a lot of images (listviews where every list item have an image, gridviews with images, gallery of images), so at the end of the development in the drawable folder will be about 1000 or more images. Right now I have about 200 images in drawable folder.

Is it right to put all the images in the drawable folder or which is the optimal way to add them ?

Images are used for:

- Gridview
- ListView for each Gridview Item
- Gallery for each listView item

Comment: In what way do you mean optimal.  Speed to read the images, or some other performance issue?  I would be most concerned about memory usage on older phones in the first instance.  The APK is a zip file so having lots of small files versus one big file may not make a lot of difference to reading speed.

Comment: I don't want to wake up at the end of development that the application is not running well not even on newer phones just because in drawable folder are 1000 images

Comment: Then get 10000 images now and performance test your app (even just the views you describe above) on a Galaxy Y or similar!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the images on SD Card. Storing in the resource folder will increase the app size.

Answer (score 0):

your apk cannot exceed 50 MB on google play here is a link on expansion packs

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling a lot of images, it is better to keep them on the assets folder.

The drawable folder, is ment to be used to store icons and backgrounds, and in some cases where you don't have a lot of images, i can be used to store images for lists and grids. This is because images on drawable are preloaded onto memory, so if you have a lot of images in high-res, they can consume all of the device's ram memory.

On the other hand, the assets folder is perfect for this case, since the images are stored as raw images and when you want to use them, you have to build them as bitmaps, so you are responsible for building them and using them when you need them.

Storing the images on assets also means that you have to be aware of your memory consumption, because if you load a list or a grid with a lot of high-res images, you're going to fill up your ram anyway. I suggest making your lists and grids using holders, so whenever an item is not showing on screen it's not stored on ram.

And if you need to display multiple high-res images on screen at the same time, i suggest building them with BitmapFactory.options.inSampleSize. This allows you to pass size parameters to the bitmap you're about to build, so you don't build a bitmap that is to large in comparison to the size of the container that's going to store it

Answer (score 0):

Image from Resources loading faster (simply by ID).
But if you store 1000+ images, your app will be huge.
So my advice: keep images as zip on some web server, after user first install your app, you should download and unzip it to SD card folder.